# How to make different data display in a modal based on which component is clicked

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I Have code for a Modal to display when a component is clicked. The components are created based on an Aura:Iteration so I need a way for the modal to display data based on which event is clicked. The current code is trying to take the list of event and article wrappers and match the Id of whatever event is clicked and then set current event to that event. I've tried many different references to the current event attribute but it doesn't seem to be clicking.

As it stands the Id is being set properly, I believe the issue lies with how i am retrieving the list data and setting the current event attribute. Code below:

CurrentEvent attribute which I am trying to set to a single event in my list of event and article wrappers:

```
 <aura:attribute name="currentEvent" type="sObject"/>
```

Modal code:

```
  <!--Use "slds-m-around_xx-large" class to add standard X-Large padding to the component--> 
<div class="slds-m-around_xx-large" style="width: 100%;">
    <!--Use aura:if tag to display Model Box, on the bese of conditions. [isOpen boolean attribute] -->   
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">
        <!--###### MODAL BOX Start######--> 
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Start ######-->
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                          onclick="{! c.closeModel }"
                                          alternativeText="close"
                                          variant="bare-inverse"
                                          class="slds-modal__close"/>
                    <h4 id="event-Title" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Title: {!currentEvent.Title__c}</h4>
                </header>
                <!--###### MODAL BOX BODY Part Start######-->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <span><b>Time: </b><lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!wrapper.event.Start_Date__c}" year="numeric" month="short" day="2-digit" weekday="short" hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit" timeZoneName="short"/> - <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!v.currentEvent.End_Date__c}" year="numeric" month="short" day="2-digit" weekday="short" hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit" timeZoneName="short"/></span><br/>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!wrapper.event.Location__c != null}">
                        <span><b>Location: </b>{!wrapper.event.Location__c}</span><br/>
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!wrapper.event.Product_Filter__c != null}">
                        <span><b>Products: </b>{!wrapper.event.Product_Filter__c}</span><br/>
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!wrapper.event.Event_Type_Filter__c != null}">
                        <span><b>Event Type: </b>{!wrapper.event.Event_Type_Filter__c}</span><br/>
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!wrapper.event.Tags__c != null}">
                        <span><b>Tags: </b>{!wrapper.event.Tags__c}</span><br/>
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!wrapper.event.Agenda_Public_Link__c != null}">
                        <span><b>Agenda: </b><a href="{!wrapper.event.Agenda_Public_Link__c}" target="_blank"> Download </a></span><br/>
                    </aura:if>
                    <br/>
                    <p><ui:outputRichText value="{!wrapper.event.Description__c}"/></p>
                </div>
                <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start ######-->
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">

                    <aura:if isTrue="{!wrapper.event.Event_Past__c}">
                        <!--If the event has a register link and is in the future -->
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!wrapper.event.Registration_Link__c != null}">
                            <a href="{!wrapper.event.Registration_Link__c}" target="_blank" class=" slds-button slds-button_brand btn"> Register </a>
                            <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <a href="" target="_blank" class="slds-button slds-button_brand disabled"> Register </a>
                            </aura:set>
                        </aura:if>

                        <aura:set attribute="else">
                            <!--If the event has a recording link and is in the past -->
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!wrapper.event.Recording_Link__c != null}">
                                <a href="{!wrapper.event.Recording_Link__c}" target="_blank" class=" slds-button slds-button_brand btn"> Recording </a>
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    <a href="" target="_blank" class="slds-button slds-button_brand disabled"> Recording </a>
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
                        </aura:set>
                    </aura:if>

                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        <!--###### MODAL BOX Part END Here ######-->
         </aura:if>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
     openModal: function(component, event, helper) {
  // Set isModalOpen attribute to true
  var id = event.target.closest("section").id;
            console.log('Id: ' + id);
    var eventList = component.get("v.listOfWrappers");
            console.log('List: ' + eventList);
            var event;

            for(var i = 0; i < eventList.length; i++){
                if(eventList[i].Id == id){
                    event = eventList[i];
                    component.set("v.currentEvent", event); 
                }
            }
  console.log('current event: ' + v.currentEvent);  
  component.set("v.isOpen", true);
```

},

Comment: Mind specifying where you are stuck in your code? As is,  your question seems pretty much open ended, or are you expecting a code review? If so, your question might get closed as too broad or out of scope

Comment: I updated the info above, Hopefully that is more clear. I am trying to grab my list of wrappers and set the current event attribute to the event that was clicked in my list of cards. I believe the issue lies with my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was: In the for loop I was using to match the section Id to an event ID I needed to call eventList.event.Id instead of just eventList.Id since some of the objects in my list were not events.